# How to add pypi packages as a dependency to normal debian package

Tags: debian, package

I am generating a debian package (not a python package) which will use PYPI packages like pyang, watchdog, Genshi, which are not available in the standard Ubuntu/debian repository.

How can I add these dependencies to .deb file. 
  Above dependencies need to install automatically When install the .deb using apt-get.

Comment: You'll need to make deb packages out of these dependencies and depend on them.

Comment: Suppose my package depends 10 pypi packages. it is very difficult to maintain  and  make  deb package for these dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I see. But there is no clean way around.

Answer (score 0):

I would adjust your application to use [dh-virtualenv](https://github.com/spotify/dh-virtualenv) as this will solve this--and other--issues.